# Undoing acceptance of an answer. Does it affect the reputation of the user who has answered?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

If a questioner, at some point in time, feels that a provided answer does not fit to the scenario or the code has some bug, then:

1. Is it alright to unaccept the answer (my main concern)?
2. If yes, then does it affect the reputation of the user who had answered?

Comment: Yes; see in the first answer to the duplicate: `You lose reputation when: one of your formerly accepted answers loses accepted status: -15`

Comment: Thanks for the information @DavidRobinson. Appreciate that.

Comment: One thing you can do to reduce how often this happens is to not accept an answer too quickly. I think it makes sense to wait at least 1-2 days before accepting an answer. This makes it less likely that you'll have to change it. And it also encourages more (and possibly better) answers, because people will be less likely to answer questions that already have an accepted answer. But if another answer than the one you initially accepted turns out to help you more, there's nothing wrong with accepting a different answer.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you mark an answer as accepted, the owner of that answer gets +15 reputation points. Those are indeed taken away if you unaccept their answer. If you choose a different answer to accept, then that other user will get the +15.

You shouldn't really take that into account though if the answer has a problem. We don't want incorrect answers sticking at the top of the answer list.

Select the best answer that solves your problem, or the one you found the most helpful to you. That can change over time: maybe a new answer comes up with a better solution, or perhaps you've become more familiar with the issue and you realize that one of the other approaches was in fact more appropriate. Change your accepted answer in that case.